# separate files for constant values in asp.net mvc appliaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm planning to design an asp.net MVC web application which keeps its constant values such as **Page Titles, Label Values, Tooltips, Page Headers, Menu titles** and etc. in a separate common location.

when I do this research one way to this achieve this expectation, is using **resource files (.resx)**

So I found this article [Create Multi-Language WebSite in Asp.Net MVC – Localization](http://www.codedigest.com/posts/53/create-multi-language-website-in-aspnet-mvc---localization)
I did hands-on project, which retrieves label names from **layout** files and HTML pages and its working properly.

But it seems, usage of **resource files (.resx)** is to achieve **Localization**

So I have following ambiguities

1. If this is not the best way, what are the other alternatives
2. If this is a good approach, will it affect application performance(like lagging the website than accessing directly from HTML pages)

Comment: `will it affect application performance` the answer to this type of question is often `try it yourself and see`

Comment: @Steve Yeah, I'll before jump to the pool, I just asked the nature of the pool :D

Comment: Of course you can also save your stuff in a database.

Answer (score 2):

I don't often use .resx for resources, but that's just personal preference.
They work fine and I have never run into performance issues with them.

For localization and similar string resources, I usually create a JSON file and make it an embedded resource instead. The benefit to this is that it's easier to work with outside of Visual Studio and .NET.

That's just an alternative though. Either practice is fine.

Comment: Thanks i'll see more example with JSON file loading